# Direct3DCreate9Ex returns D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE (0x8876086a) when running as Windows Service

Tags: windows, direct3d

For some reasons, I have to create D3D9 in my program, which is running as a service.

But I got `D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE` for the following code:

```
ATL::CComPtr<IDirect3D9Ex> d3d9 = nullptr;
HRESULT hr = ::Direct3DCreate9Ex(D3D_SDK_VERSION, &d3d9);
```

And it works if it's not running in a service.

I saw someone success to do this by checking `Allow service to interact with desktop` in the Control Panel, but it doesn't work for me.

Is there any setting I have to mention?

Comment: It would not be particularly surprising to me if this is impossible.  What are you trying to use D3D9 to do?  (You can't display anything from a service, so on the face of it there would seem to be no point.)

Comment: I want to do some video analysis on the decoded frame.
It won't be necessary to display any information on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Vista and later, Windows Services run in an isolated context (called 'session 0 isolation') to reduce threats from malware. In some cases, you can create a NULL device and possibly a WARP device, but Direct3D GPU access from a Windows Service is not available until Windows 8.

See [KB 978635](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978635)